# Rails/SQL: count the number of consecutive records having a specific status

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to count the number of groups of consecutive requests, having a specific status.

```
Example:

Request 1 status=bad
Request 2 status=good
Request 3 status=good
Request 4 status=bad
Request 5 status=bad
Request 6 status=bad
Request 7 status=good
Request 8 status=bad
```

So we're having here two groups of consecutive `good`: `[2, 3] and [7]`.

The goal then is to have `result = 2`.

Here is what I'm using right now:

```
Request.group("date(created_at)").count
```

With a result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, date(created_at) AS date_created_at FROM "requests" GROUP BY date(created_at)

{Wed, 07 Aug 2019=>240, Mon, 05 Aug 2019=>245, Tue, 06 Aug 2019=>511}
```

But this counts all requests, not the number of consecutive `good`.

Comment: Can you just add .where(status: "good") to your query? Request.where(status: "good").group("date(created_at)").count

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
Request.group('DATE(created_at)', :status).count
```

This gives the result

```
a = {[Fri, 15 Jun 2012, "good"]=2, [Fri, 30 Jan 2015, "good"]=>1, [Thu, 02 Oct 2008, "bad"]=>3, [Thu, 26 Jul 2018, "good"]=>1}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work, it just counts the number per status, not the number of consecutive good.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by creating chunks and then count like this

```
Request.order("created_at").all.map(&:status).chunk{|status| status=="good"}.count{|good_group_count,arr| good_group_count}
```

Also we can select only status column to optimise query like below

```
Request.order("created_at").select("status").map(&:status).chunk{|status| status=="good"}.count{|good_group_count,arr| good_group_count}
```